# How to apply CSS to Selected One in Meteor?

Tags: css, meteor

I need to apply `CSS` to Selected One in `Meteor JS`.I did a sample example with a list of names then when ever clicks a name then get details of that name.**So here i need to highlight the clicked name in a list of names**.In this sample exe i get names using Publish/Subscribe methods.So how to highlight the selected one in a list of names.Please see the below code and css [Here css hover will works but active not working ]& suggest me what to do?

Template Code :

```
<template name="client">
    <div style="float:left;">
    <div style="float:left;">
   <h2> Clients List</h2>
    {{#each clientname}}      
             <div class="client {{isselected}}">{{name}}</div> 
    {{/each}}
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;padding-left:400px;">
    {{> clientmaincontent}}
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="clientdata">
<div>
<h1> This is Client Data</h1>
<div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;">Name : {{cname}}</div></br>
<div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;">ID : {{id}}</div> </br>
<div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;">Hcare : {{hcare}}</div> 
</div>
</template>
```

CSS :

```
  .client .selected
 {
  background-color: red;
 }
.client {
    cursor: pointer;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    border:4px solid #eeeee8;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 4px;
   // float:left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#eeeee8;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

JS Code :

```
Template.client.events
          ({
            'click .client' : function (e,t)
            {

              // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
              if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
              //alert("You pressed the button");
                console.log("You pressed the Client button");
                e.preventDefault();
                 Session.set("selectedClient", this.name);
                        }
              });
Template.client.isselected = function ()
             {
                console.log("Hello DD="+Session.equals("selectedClient", this.name) ? "selected" : '');
                return Session.equals("selectedClient", this.name) ? "selected" : '';
              };
```

Comment: You could do it with two classes and an event handler.  jQuery is usually available on the client side.

Comment: How to do as you told.@Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Though it would probably better not to store the client name in the session variable but a more unique identifier. `{{isSelected}}` inserts `selected` into the list of classes if the client name equals the name stored in the session variable `selectedClient`.

HTML:

```
<!-- in some other template -->
{{#each clientname}}      
  {{> client}}
{{/each}}

<template name="client">
   <div class="client {{isSelected}}">{{name}}</div> 
</template>
```

JS (wrap in `Meteor.isClient`):

```
Template.client.events({
  'click': function () {
    Session.set("selectedClient", this.name);
  }
});

Template.client.isSelected = function () {
  return Session.equals("selectedClient", this.name) ? "selected" : '';
};
```

CSS:

```
.client .selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did as you told above and also check the `return value given  selected when clicks any name` but css is not applied.Can you please give me suggestion what mistake i did?.@Tobold.

Comment: It is hard to point out your mistake without seeing some more code. Can you maybe update the code in your question? Maybe check that nothing is wrong with your css (maybe you have some conflicting information in there).

Comment: Yeah,In this time i update my code So can you check once please?.@Tobold.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see a problem. Since your code is not really clean and contains unnecessary stuff I would suggest you remove some of the code until you reach a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) and then post again. In the process you will probably find the mistake on your own. Most confusing for me is what your data contexts look like (you have `client` and `clientname` and `name` in `clientname`? This seems odd and could be the issue.)

Comment: Yeah, It works successfully until now but nothing change even though  now `i get this.name value is undefined`. So what i can do for this problem.@Tobold.